# custom validator in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, validation, symfony-1.4

I would like create custom validator for Symfony 1.4, for example check length name. I know that it exist, but i would like own.

I create /myapp/lib/validator/sfValidatorName.class.php

Must be there:

```
class sfValidatorName extends sfValidatorBase
{

  protected function configure($options = array(),
                                $messages = array()) {

      $this->addMessage('invalid', 'Invalid name!');
  }

  protected function doClean($value) {

  }
}
```

and how can i add for this my function, for example:

```
    if (count($letters) < 3) {
        return 'too small';
    } else if (count($letters) > 43) {
        return 'too long'; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open /lib/validator/sfValidatorString.class.php
2. Model your validator after that one.

Answer (score 1):

Since your example is exactly what sfValidatorString does, why don't you go look at it's source? Basically you just throw a validation error with the relevant error code (eg. invalid, min_length, max_length, ...).

By default any validator has the errors 'invalid' and 'required', but you can add your own with addMessage().

For this specific example, a much smarter choice is to configure or extend sfValidatorString.

Comment: i would like to learn create own validator for this simple example

Comment: Then why don't you follow my advice and have a look at sfValidatorString.